# Как в kv-файле использовать русские буквы?

Tags: python, kivy

Пытаюсь парсить kv-файл, но в нём русский алфавит и это вызывает ошибку кодировки:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
143: character maps to <undefined>
```

Что можно с этим сделать?
Вот код:

```
<Container_1>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 50
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.4
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.1}
        text: 'История'
        font_size: 40
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.4
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.1}
        text: 'Провести диагностику'
        font_size: 40
        on_release:
            root.transition_1()
```

Comment: Пару уточнений. У вас python 2 или 3? Посмотрите, в какой кодировке сохранен файл (например, через notepad++ в строке состояния)

Comment: Python 3, кодировка UTF-8 в главном файле и в .kv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом [issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4003) предлагают открывать файл в нужной кодировке, считывать в строку, и из строки билдить интерфейс:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f: 
    Builder.load_string(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

А еще лучше завести вот такой вот метод в главном классе `App`:

```
def load_all_kv_files(self, directory_kv_files):
    for kv_file in os.listdir(directory_kv_files):
        kv_file = os.path.join(directory_kv_files, kv_file)
        if os.path.isfile(kv_file) and kv_file.endswith("kv"):
            with open(kv_file, encoding="utf-8") as kv:
                Builder.load_string(kv.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

у меня не было подобной ошибки - просто заместо русских букевок были каракули. я сменил кодировку на Windows-1251 - самого kv файла (редактор Notepad++) - и поехало - буквы стали русскими!

Comment: кодировка была UTF-8 тоже кстати.